# WaitforSingleObject missed a signal event

Tags: c++, multithreading

I checked related posts but still cannot get the answer. Experts, please help me on this.
I basically has two threads, one thread recv data from the ethernet and the other process the received data. To get the maximum performance, ThreadRecv recv nth frame and ThreadCompute Process (n-1)th frame. I recorded the timing relation and found that if the event is signaled before the Wait function, it will not get the event.

Here is the rough code:

```
st_threads::st_threads():Event_ComputeDone(0,0),Sem_KillThread(0,2),
        Sem_PauseThread(0,2),Sem_ResumeThread(0,2),Event_RecvDone(0,0),
        Event_RecvTerminated(0,0),Event_RecvPaused(0,0),Event_RecvStart(0,0),//make it automatic
        Event_ComputeTerminated(0,0),Event_ComputePaused(0,0)
{
    ping_num=0;
    thread_state=stopped;
    step=1;
    //threadHandles[0]=0;
    //threadHandles[1]=0;
}

UINT st_threads::ThreadRecv(LPVOID pParam)
{
    st_threads *pThread=(st_threads*)pParam; //get the pointer
    hptime t0;
    double dtime,dtime0;
    while(1)
    {
        dtime0=t0.gettime();
        //check if terminate the thread

        if(pThread->ping_num)
        WaitForSingleObject(pThread->Event_RecvStart,INFINITE);


        //realtime processing
        dtime=t0.gettime();
        switch(pThread->work_mode)
        {
        case realtime_mode:
            //if(pThread->ECP->IsAlive())
            {
                pThread->frame_len=pThread->ECP->RecvDataFrame(pThread->rawbuf,MAX_RAW_BUF_SIZE); //receive a data frame into a buffer
                if(pThread->frame_len<192)
                {
                    pThread->frame_len=pThread->ECP->RecvDataFrame(pThread->rawbuf,MAX_RAW_BUF_SIZE); //receive a data frame into a buffer
                }
                if(pThread->frame_len<0)
                {
                    TRACE("recv error\n");
                }
                pThread->pdatalist->push_back(raw_data(pThread->frame_len,pThread->rawbuf,pThread->ping_num));
                pThread->praw_frame[pThread->ping_num%2]=--pThread->pdatalist->raw_buf.end();
            }
            break;

        default:break;
        }

        pThread->ping_num++;
        pThread->Event_RecvDone.SetEvent(); //let compute to start

        pThread->threadtime.time_ThreadRecv=dtime0;
        pThread->threadtime.dt_recv=t0.gettime()-dtime;
        pThread->threadtime.dt_ThreadRecv=t0.gettime()-pThread->threadtime.time_ThreadRecv;
        //
        //TRACE("RECV:ping#=%d\n",pThread->ping_num);

    }

    AfxEndThread(0);
    return 0;
}

UINT st_threads::ThreadCompute(LPVOID pParam)
{
    st_threads *pThread=(st_threads*)pParam;

    int prev_frame_time=0,data_mode;
    double time_elapsed,dt,dtime0;
    hptime t0;
    while(1)
    {
        //WaitForSingleObject(pThread->Event_ComputeStart,INFINITE);
        dtime0=t0.gettime();

        WaitForSingleObject(pThread->Event_RecvDone,INFINITE);
        pThread->Event_RecvStart.SetEvent(); //let recv start at the same time as computing


        //realtime processing
        if(pThread->ping_num)
        {
            dt=t0.gettime();
            pThread->dispatch_packet(pThread->praw_frame[(pThread->ping_num-1)%2],&data_mode,pThread->ping_num-1);
            pThread->threadtime.dt_comp=t0.gettime()-dt;

                pThread->threadtime.dt_frame_interval=t0.gettime()-dtime0;

        }
        //else Sleep(100);
        pThread->Event_ComputeDone.SetEvent();

        pThread->threadtime.time_ThreadCompute=dtime0;
        pThread->threadtime.dt_ThreadCompute=dt=t0.gettime()-pThread->threadtime.time_ThreadCompute;
        if(pThread->debug_mode) pThread->logtime(pThread->ping_num,data_mode);
        //TRACE("COMP:ping#=%d, frame rate: %d\n",pThread->ping_num,int(1000.0/dt));
        //
    }
    AfxEndThread(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The program will record the timing, part of the output would be like this:

```
0177 15 364486101   23  23  364486099   23  21  23
0178 15 364486124   23  23  364486122   23  21  23
0179 15 364486147   23  23  364486145   23  20  23
0180 15 364486170   23  23  364486167   23  21  23
0181 15 364486193   23  23  364486190   23  21  23
0182 15 364486216   21  21  364486213   23  20  21
0183 15 364486238   23  23  364486236   23  21  23
0184 15 364486261   23  23  364486259   23  21  23
0185 15 364486284   22  22  364486282   23  21  22
0186 15 364486307   23  23  364486305   23  21  23
0187 15 364486330   23  23  364486328   23  21  23
0188 15 364486353   23  23  364486351   23  20  23
0189 15 364486376   23  22  364486374   23  20  23
0190 15 364486399   23  23  364486396   23  21  23
0191 15 364486422   23  23  364486420   23  21  23
0192 15 364486445   23  23  364486442   23  21  23
0193 15 364486468   23  23  364486465   23  20  23
0194 15 364486491   22  22  364486488   23  20  22
0195 15 364486513   23  23  364486511   23  21  23
0196 15 364486536   23  23  364486534   23  21  23
0197 15 364486559   22  22  364486557   23  21  22
0198 15 364486582   23  23  364486580   23  21  23
0199 15 364486605   23  23  364486603   23  20  23
0200 15 364486628   23  23  364486625   25  23  23
0200 15 364486651   23  23  364486625   25  23  23
0201 15 364486674   24  22  364486650   26  25  24
0202 15 364486698   25  22  364486676   25  25  25
0203 15 364486723   26  23  364486701   25  25  26
0204 15 364486749   25  23  364486726   25  25  25
0205 15 364486774   24  22  364486751   25  25  24
0206 15 364486798   26  22  364486776   26  26  26
0207 15 364486825   24  21  364486802   25  25  24
0208 15 364486849   25  22  364486827   25  25  25
0209 15 364486874   25  22  364486852   25  25  25
0210 15 364486900   25  22  364486877   25  25  25
0211 15 364486925   25  22  364486902   26  25  25
0212 15 364486950   25  22  364486928   25  25  25
0213 15 364486975   26  22  364486953   26  26  26
0214 15 364487001   26  22  364486979   26  26  26
0215 15 364487027   24  22  364487004   25  25  24
0216 15 364487051   25  22  364487029   25  25  25
0217 15 364487076   29  22  364487054   29  29  29
0218 15 364487106   26  23  364487083   26  26  26
0219 15 364487132   25  22  364487109   26  26  25
```

The first column is the ping number, 2nd is not related, 3rd is absolute time for ThreadCompute, 4th is duration time for ThreadCompute, 5th not releated, 6th is for ThreadRecv, 7th is duration time for threadRecv.
Note that we get two identical output with ping number 200. It shows that the threadrecv is a little bit slower than ThreadCompute. The recvStart is issued earlier than the Wait function, and it is not received.

Comment: Signaling an event that is already signaled has no effect. It does not wake waiters twice. If you want waiters to signal twice, you need a semaphore. Make sure you understand the different synchronization objects before you decide which one to use.

Comment: hello Raymond, thank you for the comment, however it is not the case here. The wait function did not return if the event is signaled earlier. That is my problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a totally wrong design.

```
 WaitForSingleObject(pThread->Event_RecvDone,INFINITE);
 pThread->Event_RecvStart.SetEvent(); //let recv start at the same time as computing
```

You wait on a packet (identified by ping_num) to be received and tell the Receiver thread to go on receiving and *then* start processing the packet. The Receiver thread could increments ping_num *BEFORE* the Computing thread finishes processing the just received packet. That's totally possible in a multithreaded environment.

I think you should re-design the logic of receive/compute process. Better use a list or queue to store received packets in Receiver thread and extract them in Computing thread. Of course you have to use Mutex or other means to protect the list/queue.

Comment: Nim, Thank you for the input. It is a good point that the ping_num might be increased in the Recv thread before the computing. However it will not cause big problem since the packet is ready when the ping_num++, only possible a packet is not processed. The problem seen from the output indicates that at ping_num=200, the recv time increases and then RecvThread is blocked and did not get the Event until the next compute loop.

Comment: Please re-read my answer and you code. It's very wrong, you're depending on time sequence and hope that ping_num++ must happen after your packet processing code.

Comment: I re-studied your code and I found no problem with Set/Wait lockings. The only problem is that ping_num is not protected but yet used by two threads; even worse it is used unguarded in several places.

Comment: Thanks nim for your input, I am sorry for reporting back late. Yes, Nim you are mostly right. The file debugging has some problems. When outputting debugging information, I cannot guarantee the information from the recv thread is correct, or the ThreadRecv is not in well-defined states, so I rewrite the code to wait for the ThreadRecv to complete and write the debug file. Also I move the ping_num++ to the ThreadCompute and let the ThreadCompute to be the master threads to control the RecvThread. Problem is not found. So the conclusion is that event will not be missed. Thank you all

Comment: Sorry, can you make my 1st reply as answer? Thanks.